# Print specific string from url from database

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match

This is a sample url from the database "fishPrice/1572268723Career Portal.pdf" I want to print the file name only which is "Career Portal" What is the best way to do it?

I've tried using `preg_match` but I'm getting "undefined offset error"

`$fishPrice['price']` contains the url

```
<?php

if(!empty($fishPrices))
{
    foreach ($fishPrices as $fishPrice)
    {
        $date = strtotime($fishPrice['Date']);
        $url = $fishPrice['price'];
        $pattern = "[0-9]/";
        preg_match('[0-9]', $url, $matches);
        $price = $matches[1];
        ?>

        <div class="">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                <div class="container-outer">
                    <div class="container-inner ">
                        <div class="images-left">
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x270" alt="girl-heart">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-cont-right">
                            <div class="images-text">
                                <h3><a href="features-ecology.html"><?= date('M j Y', $date)?></a></h3>

                                <p><?= $price ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a href="admin/<?=$fishPrice['price']?>" class="green-btn green-btn-news">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
```

Comment: Depends on the structure of the url. Does it always have numbers before the correct name? Does your printed name contains numbers aswell?

Comment: No we are not gonna put numbers on the printed name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, using `preg_match` with a capture group:

```
$input = "fishPrice/1572268723Career Portal.pdf";
preg_match("/.*\d{10}(.*)\.\w+$/", $input, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

This prints `Career Portal`.  The regex logic here is to capture everything after the final 10 digit number sequence, but before the file extension.

Comment: Thank you Tim do you mind explaining why my code did not work earlier, was my regex wrong?

Comment: Your regex is missing delimiters, but more important is that your pattern `[0-9]` would just match a single number, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to parse it earlier but decided to use preg_match since it's more appropriate for what my need but regex characters are confusing.

Comment: Do you still have another question?

Answer (score 1):

With only one sample string, the pattern accuracy is speculative.

My best guess is: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7af5v))

```
$input = "fishPrice/1572268723Career Portal.pdf";
echo preg_match("~\d{10}\K[^.]+~", $input, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail';
```

Output:

```
Career Portal
```

Just match the non-dot characters after 10 digits.

The `\K` means: forget the previously matched characters or "keep" the characters from this point. This spares the need to use a capture group.

---

Alternatively, you could use a *potentially* more reliable non-regex technique.  Here are two: ([Demo2](https://3v4l.org/KtPdT))

```
echo ltrim(basename($input, '.pdf'), '0..9');
echo "\n---\n";
echo ltrim(pathinfo($input, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '0..9');
```

Output:

```
Career Portal
---
Career Portal
```

Isolate the filename, then left trim all digits.

Comment: Wow this looks much easier thank you, first time seeing a function called ltrim perhaps I could use this in the future.

Comment: @JohnMacasinag Please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329

Answer (score -1):

Okay I worked on a little example for you.

```
$string = "fishPrice/1572268723Career Portal.pdf";

//Echo 1572268723Career Portal.pdf
$string =  substr($string, strpos($string, "/")+1);

while(is_numeric($string[0]))
{
     $string = substr($string, 1);
}

//Career Portal.pdf
echo $string;
```

First of all, I substring to the / with should be always there as you said. Thereafter I will cut the numbers until I get a valid character, which will be the beginn of the name. Hope that helps!

Comment: `I want to print the file name only`

Comment: So without the pdf? For me .pdf contains to the file name.

Comment: 23 function calls?  I wouldn't recommend that anyone should entertain such an inefficient technique.